# Implement interface's IEnumerable<BaseClass> with IEnumerable<DerivedClass>?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm implementing an interface that has a member `IEnumerable<BaseClass> Member`. But I'd like to store some extra information in each `BaseClass` item, for which I've created a derived class. This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
interface IImplementMe
{
    IEnumerable<BaseClass> Member { get; }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Some extra stuff here
}

class Implementation : IImplementMe
{
    IEnumerable<DerivedClass> Member { get; }
}
```

I don't think there's a way to do this (if there is please let me know!). There may be repeated items in the `Member` list, so I cannot use a dictionary to store the extra stuff. What would it be the standard, elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` have an inheritance relationship, that doesn't mean that `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` (where `G` is a generic type with one type argument) have the same inheritance relationship. In fact, they have no inheritance relationship.

Comment: Interfaces cannot have fields, so does the property have a getter and a setter or only a getter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explicit interface implementations for this.

```
class Implementation : IImplementMe
{
    public IEnumerable<DerivedClass> Member;

    IEnumerable<BaseClass> IImplementMe.Member { get { return Member; } }
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure this will work, assuming one fixes the compilation errors. This is a standard way to do it.

Comment: @mikez: Sorry, you are right. I didn't expect the cast to work, but since it is an interface, it will work.

Comment: Yes! This is because `IEnumerable` is `IEnumerable<out T>` isn't it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, I guess technically it will work only when compiling to .NET 4 or higher. That was when generic variance was introduced.

Comment: @mikez: Then I missed that feature. I remembered this didn't work, but now it does. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, yes, this is possible because of the `out` keyword in `IEnumerable<out T>`. Is called generic variance as mike said.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options I think:

1. Use the derived class as type parameter:

   ```
   interface IImplementMe<T> where T : BaseClass
   {
       IEnumerable<T> Member;
   }

   class DerivedClass : BaseClass
   {
       // Some extra stuff here
   }

   class Implementation : IImplementMe<DerivedClass>
   {
       IEnumerable<DerivedClass> Member;
   }
   ```
2. Use `IEnumerable`:

   ```
   interface IImplementMe
   {
       IEnumerable Member;
   }

   class DerivedClass : BaseClass
   {
       // Some extra stuff here
   }

   class Implementation : IImplementMe
   {
       IEnumerable Member;
   }
   ```